# why I can not remove all spaces from a column of a pyspark df

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to remove spaces from a column of my dataframe. I tried many many ways but still I see some spaces at the end of some elements:

here is what I tried:

```
data_us2 = data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name', F.regexp_replace("clean_company_name", r"(^ +)|( +)$", ""))
data_us2 = data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name', F.regexp_replace("clean_company_name", r"\\s+", ""))
data_us2 = data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name', F.regexp_replace("clean_company_name", r"(^ +)|( +)$", ""))
data_us2 = data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name', trim(data_us2.clean_company_name))
```

any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data_us2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "This is Spark   "),
    (1, "I wish Java could use case classes  "),
    (2, "Data science is  cool  "),
    (3, "Machine  ")
], ["id", "clean_company_name"]).drop('id')

data_us2.show(truncate=False)
```

#Remove leading and trailing spaces alone

```
data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim('clean_company_name')).show(truncate=False)
```

#Remove all spaces in string and ensure no leading and trailing spaces

```
data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim(regexp_replace('clean_company_name','\s',''))).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: No your `regexp_replace` also remove spaces between words

Comment: I gave you two options I think. Use the first one `data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim('clean_company_name')).show(truncate=False)`

Comment: I used it before, still I have space infront of the words. can't understant why

Comment: Possible they are not white spaces. Maybe try `data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim(regexp_replace('clean_company_name','[^\w^\s]',''))).show(truncate=False)`

Answer (score 0):

try: `print(data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim(col('clean_company_name'))).collect())` to print ur result.

```
data_us2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, " This is Spark   "),
    (1, "   I wish Java could use case classes  "),
    (2, " Data science is  cool  "),
    (3, "  Machine  ")
], ["id", "clean_company_name"]).drop('id')

data_us2.show(truncate=False)
# +---------------------------------------+
# |clean_company_name                     |
# +---------------------------------------+
# | This is Spark                         |
# |   I wish Java could use case classes  |
# | Data science is  cool                 |
# |  Machine                              |
# +---------------------------------------+

print(data_us2.withColumn('clean_company_name',trim(col('clean_company_name'))).collect())
# [Row(clean_company_name='This is Spark'), Row(clean_company_name='I wish Java could use case classes'), Row(clean_company_name='Data science is  cool'), Row(clean_company_name='Machine')]
```